# Wiring up redux-form with saga and typescript

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-form, redux-saga

I am trying to get my head around React, Redux, Saga and Typescript. I managed to follow an example to wire up a simple page that displayed data in a table. I am now trying to create a login form. I have followed various different examples. I think the actions, reducer, saga and types parts are OK but I am really struggling to connect the actual page up to work.

Below is what I have so far and I am looking for some guidance on how I can get this to work.

**Typescript Errors**
The following typescript errors are displaying on my index.ts page:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}> //[ts] Expected 5 arguments, but got 1

<button action="submit">LOGIN</button> //[ts] Property 'action' does not exist on type ....

const formed = reduxForm({form: 'signup'})(connected) //[ts] Argument of type 'ComponentClass<Pick<AllProps, "errors" | "handleSubmit ....
```

**Problems:**

Clearly there are lots and I have been trying to work through them without much success but here is where I think I need help. 
- How can I wire up the onSubmit of the form to call my registerRequest action.
- How do I correctly connect the ReduxForm and export at the end of the index.tsx

**pages/register/index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'

import { ApplicationState, ConnectedReduxProps } from '../../store'
import { Message, Error } from '../../store/register/types'
import { registerRequest } from '../../store/register/actions'

// Separate state props + dispatch props to their own interfaces.
interface PropsFromState {
  email: string,
  password: string,
  requesting: boolean,
  successful: boolean,
  message: Message[],
  errors: Error[],
}

// We can use `typeof` here to map our dispatch types to the props, like so.
interface PropsFromDispatch {
  registerRequest: typeof registerRequest,
  handleSubmit: typeof PropTypes.func,
  signupRequest: typeof PropTypes.func,
}

// Combine both state + dispatch props - as well as any props we want to pass - in a union type.
type AllProps = PropsFromState & PropsFromDispatch & ConnectedReduxProps

class RegisterIndexPage extends React.Component<AllProps> {
  public componentDidMount() { }

  // Redux Form will call this function with the values of our
  // Form fields `email` and `password` when the form is submitted
  // this will in turn call the action
  submit = (email: string, password: string) => {
    // we could just do signupRequest here with the static proptypes
    // but ESLint doesn't like that very much...
    this.props.registerRequest(email, password)
  }

  public render() {

    // grab what we need from props.  The handleSubmit from ReduxForm
    // and the pieces of state from the global state.
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="signup">
        {/* Use the Submit handler with our own submit handler*/}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
          <h1>Register</h1>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          {
          /*
            Our Redux Form Field components that bind email and password
            to our Redux state's form -> register piece of state.
          */}
          <Field
            name="email"
            type="text"
            id="email"
            className="email"
            label="Email"
            component="input"
          />
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <Field
            name="password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            className="password"
            label="Password"
            component="input"
          />
          <button action="submit">LOGIN</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

// It's usually good practice to only include one context at a time in a connected component.
// Although if necessary, you can always include multiple contexts. Just make sure to
// separate them from each other to prevent prop conflicts.
const mapStateToProps = ({ register }: ApplicationState) => ({
  email: register.email,
  password: register.password,
  requesting: register.requesting,
  successful: register.successful,
  message: register.message,
  error: register.error,
})

// patchToProps is especially useful for constraining our actions to the connected component.
// You can access these via `this.props`.
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch, { register }: ApplicationState) => ({
  registerRequest: () => dispatch(registerRequest(register.email, register.password))
})

// Now let's connect our component!
// With redux v4's improved typings, we can finally omit generics here.

const connected = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(RegisterIndexPage)


// Connect our connected component to Redux Form.  It will namespace
// the form we use in this component as `signup`.
const formed = reduxForm({
  form: 'signup'
})(connected)

// Export our well formed component!
export default formed
```

**register/types.ts**

```
export interface RegisterUser {
  email: string
  password: string
}

export interface Message {
  body: string
  time: Date
}

export interface Error {
  body: string
  time: Date
}

export const enum RegisterActionTypes {
  SIGNUP_REQUESTING = '@@register/SIGNUP_REQUESTING',
  SIGNUP_SUCCESS = '@@register/SIGNUP_SUCCESS',
  SIGNUP_ERROR = '@@register/SIGNUP_ERROR',
}

export interface RegisterState {
  readonly email: string
  readonly password: string
  readonly requesting: boolean,
  readonly successful: boolean,
  readonly message: Message[],
  readonly error: Error[],
}
```

**register/sagas.ts**

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { RegisterActionTypes } from './types'

import { handleApiErrors } from '../../utils/handleAPIErrors'

const signupUrl = `${process.env.TEST_AUTH_API}/api/Clients`

function signupApi(email: string, password: string) {
  return fetch(signupUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  })
    .then(handleApiErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json)
    .catch((error) => { throw error })
}
function* signupFlow(action: any) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = action
    const response = yield call(signupApi, email, password)
    yield put({ type: RegisterActionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS, response })
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: RegisterActionTypes.SIGNUP_ERROR, error })
  }

}


function* signupWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest(RegisterActionTypes.SIGNUP_REQUESTING, signupFlow)
}

export default signupWatcher
```

**register/reducer.ts**

```
import { Reducer } from 'redux'
import { RegisterState, RegisterActionTypes } from './types'

const initialState: RegisterState = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
  requesting: false,
  successful: false,
  message: [],
  error: [],
}

const reducer: Reducer<RegisterState> = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RegisterActionTypes.SIGNUP_REQUESTING: {
      return {
        email: action.response.email,
        password: action.response.password,
        requesting: true,
        successful: false,
        message: [{ body: 'Signing up...', time: new Date() }],
        error: [],
      }
    }
    case RegisterActionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        email: action.response.email,
        password: action.response.password,
        error: [],
        message: [{
          body: `Successfully created account for ${action.response.email}`,
          time: new Date(),
        }],
        requesting: false,
        successful: true,
      }
    }
    case RegisterActionTypes.SIGNUP_ERROR: {
      return {
        email: action.response.email,
        password: action.response.password,
        error: state.error.concat([{
          body: action.error.toString(),
          time: new Date(),
        }]),
        message: [],
        requesting: false,
        successful: false,
      }
    }
    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}

export { reducer as registerReducer }
```

**register/actions.ts**

```
import { action } from 'typesafe-actions'
import { RegisterActionTypes } from './types'

export const registerRequest = (email: string, password: string) => action(RegisterActionTypes.SIGNUP_REQUESTING, { email, password })

export default registerRequest
```

Comment: `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>` this calls handleSubmit function on the moment when the component is mounted. The ts error with html button element is probably triggered by an error somewhere before that line.